# Problems delete statement in DB2, its very very slow

Tags: performance, db2

I am running a delete statement and never ends, so does not return me an error message .
Is there any way to know which is the reason why not end ?
The version of DB2 is v10.5.500.107

Explain Plan:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6daXBGc1CpvWF9sMTdqMUpleUE/view?usp=sharing

DDL table:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6daXBGc1CpvYmhLVHFHcVhIV3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *Why* is your statement never returning?  How much data is it deleting?  Is it waiting for a lock?  Without more detail this won't get much help.

Comment: Hi Ian. No returns error message, why ask the question. I 'm Trying to delete 558,962 records. The process does not end. I made a filter in eliminating 624 delete records and sentence takes me 2 min 28 s . it is very slow.

Comment: The version is "DB2 for Linux Unix and Windows enterprise,  trial"

Comment: You'll need to post at least the delete statement, DDL for table(s) involved and an explain plan for the statement that you're trying to execute.

Comment: Ok Ian have much reason!

Answer (score 1):

you need to commit more often. this is usual behaviour when deleting loots of rows in a big table.

I usually solve this in a loop where i select only the first x rows and delete them and put the loop in a stored procedure.